What kind of animal/creature is on the statue just outside of Hogwarts?
I find all the different creatures and things in the Wizarding World very fascinating.
As soon as you exit Hogwarts to head to Hogsmeade during the "WELCOME TO HOGSMEADE" quest, at the gates, there is a statue of some kind of animal/creature:


It looks like some kind of pig mixed with a bird for the wings.
What is this?

I don't know if that's a magical creature by itself, people online call it "winged hog", "winged boar" or "flying pig".
A speculation says that it has something to do with the school name, you know, Hogwarts.
Another theory is taken from the wikia, which states:

The existence of this creature is most likely inspired by the adynaton "when pigs fly"

